# Please make sure your password match bug Magento 1.9.1

Tags: validation, passwords, magento-1.9.1

I have been searching Google for hours regarding a nasty bug in Magento 1.9.1.

I'm using the demo setup to show the possibilities of Magento for several customers.
One customer has sent me an email she couldn't create an account.

Ok, I thought and tried the same thing and guess what... I get an error telling me "Please make sure your password match".

I already "patched" the Customer.php file by changing `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();` to `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();`

This resolves the checkout issue which has the same bug.

But this doesn't resolve to make a new account to use with Magento.

We had several update bugs with updating 1.8 all the way to 1.9 and now a bug in a fresh installation.

Are there developers out there which have fixed the account issue too?

Please let me know.

Steve

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php to the local
2. Search for function `validate()`
3. Comment //`$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`
4. Insert `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation() ? $this->getConfirmation() : $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`

This would resolve the issue for registration and checkout as well.

Comment: @enigmawebdesign can you please accept this as answer

Answer (score 0):

To solve "But this doesn't resolve making a new account to use with Magento." you need to recompile ( or turn compiler off)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your solution but compilation is not used.

What I did was install a clean Magento installation and guess what.

I can register a new account and I can use the checkout without problems.
It seems that the demo installation provided for free from www.magentocommerce.com doesn't work as it should.

Br,

Stevan